# exec*() in C++, what happens to our usual exit guarantees?

Tags: c++, exec, raii

We are faced with a task that will require to `exec` another executable to replace the current process image.

Yet it is hard to find documentation regarding the interaction of [the exec() family of function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) and the C++ runtime. In particular, are any of the guarantees that we are lucky enough to take for granted still holding?

- Stack unwinding with invocation of destructors (for automatic, thread local and static variables)
- Invocation of `std::atexit()` callback

Comment: Given: _"...are front-ends for execve..."_ and _"...execve() __does not return on success__, and the text, data, bss, and stack of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded...."_ (source: https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) .  I think you have no guarantees at all.

Comment: `exec*` replaces the process with a different process and doesn't return. If the call is successful, the "old" process just vanishes without a trace.

Comment: On success, no stack unwinding, because the stack is gone.  No invocation of `std::atexit()` because the process did not exit.

Comment: Thank you all, I guess any of those can be made into an answer then!